# How to filter a dataset in React base on two columns to get only the unique data combinations?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to filter the following dataset to create a dataset that only contains unique values based on Version and Name.

```
Data = [{Id: 1, Version: "set1", Name: "apple", Location: "US"},
        {Id: 2, Version: "set1", Name: "apple", Location: "US"},
        {Id: 3, Version: "set2", Name: "apple", Location: "US"},
        {Id: 4, Version: "set1", Name: "banana", Location: "GER"},
        {Id: 5, Version: "set1", Name: "banana", Location: "GER"},
        {Id: 6, Version: "set3", Name: "cake", Location: "UK"},
        {Id: 7, Version: "set3", Name: "cake", Location: "UK"},
        {Id: 8, Version: "set3", Name: "cake", Location: "UK}]
```

The desired outcome:

```
Data = [{Id: 1, Version: "set1", Name: "apple", Location: "US"}
        {Id: 2, Version: "set2", Name: "apple", Location: "US"},
        {Id: 3, Version: "set1", Name: "banana", Location: "GER"},            
        {Id: 4, Version: "set3", Name: "cake", Location: "UK"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code.

```
let result = [];
data.forEach(val => {
    const part1 = result.filter(value => value["Name"] == val["Name"]);
    const part2 = result.filter(value => value["Name"] == val["Name"] && value["Version"] == val["Version"]);
    if(part1.length == 0 || (part1.length > 0 && part2.length == 0)) result.push(val);
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Data = [{Id: 1, Version: "set1", Name: "apple", Location: "US"},
        {Id: 2, Version: "set1", Name: "apple", Location: "US"},
        {Id: 3, Version: "set2", Name: "apple", Location: "US"},
        {Id: 4, Version: "set1", Name: "banana", Location: "GER"},
        {Id: 5, Version: "set1", Name: "banana", Location: "GER"},
        {Id: 6, Version: "set3", Name: "cake", Location: "UK"},
        {Id: 7, Version: "set3", Name: "cake", Location: "UK"},
        {Id: 8, Version: "set3", Name: "cake", Location: "UK"}]
const lookup = []      
const filtered = Data.map(d => {
  if(lookup.includes(d.Version+d.Name)){
    return null
  }else{
    lookup.push(d.Version+d.Name)
    return d
  }
}).filter(data => data !== null)
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution for filtering any array. Just get load `Lodash` install in your app using `npm` OR you can use `CDN` either way.

```js
let Data = [{Id: 1, Version: "set1", Name: "apple", Location: "US"},
        {Id: 2, Version: "set1", Name: "apple", Location: "US"},
        {Id: 3, Version: "set2", Name: "apple", Location: "US"},
        {Id: 4, Version: "set1", Name: "banana", Location: "GER"},
        {Id: 5, Version: "set1", Name: "banana", Location: "GER"},
        {Id: 6, Version: "set3", Name: "cake", Location: "UK"},
        {Id: 7, Version: "set3", Name: "cake", Location: "UK"},
        {Id: 8, Version: "set3", Name: "cake", Location: "UK"}]
        
        const result=_.uniqBy(Data, (e)=>{
        return [e.Name, e.Version].join();
        })
        console.log(result)
```

***`Happy Coding!`***